# How much data is entered in database?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get how much information user entered in database?
For example on profile page I want to show user something like:

```
Your profile is 25% complete! Please enter all information in your profile.
```

I want to get that data and set it in variable so I can use it in jQuery progressbar.
But calculate only necessary fields. For Example if user not entered middle name but everything else did profile completion will be still 100%.

Comment: That's pretty subjective and depends on the interpretation that your application gives to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must calculate it yourself. If you allow a user to enter 10 columns of personal information, and he filled 3 of them with data, then his profile is 30% done.
If he filled 8 its 80‰ done.

```
100 / totalcols * filledcols
```

That is if all fields have an equal weight. If you have 10 columns but two of them are more important, you could count then double. Then you have 10 + 2 = 12 totalcols

UPDATE

```
//cols: name, surname, addres
$total = 3;
$filled =0;

if (!empty($name))
  $filled++;

if (!empty($surname))
  $filled++;

if (!empty($address))
  $filled++;

 $p = 100/$total*$filled;
echo $p;
```

Comment: But how if I use if() function first if will be for example name, so if(!empty($name)){$p=1}elseif(!empty($name) and !empty($surname){$p=2} it always gets me to first war because the condition is true and it will give me $p=1

Comment: updated my question with an if statement.

Comment: That works thx. But now I'm trying to find faster solution?

Answer (score 3):

Well, establish weight for each field. You can add weight directly to a (new) field in the database. Then perform a query that selects all fields with information (for each user) and combines all weights. Then output total weight.

If you have no weights, and all fields are equal, just do

(fix to your fields and tables) `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_DATA WHERE USERID=1` -- it should give you how many fields are filled for that user (assuming that there are no records for empty fields). Then, you need to know how many fields are total and do some math to get a percentage.

Nevertheless, this s very vague question and you need to give us some database schema and sample data for us to give you a good answer.

If you don't really know how to do SQL and coding, you can tweak it a bit via JavaScript -- add JS fields checker in the end of the page and output this data via JS

```
<script>
var str = document.getElementById("put_your_uniqe_field_id_here").value;
alert(str);
</script>
```

Comment: OK, but how to do that?
I have in database

id
name
surname
email
phone
address

how to add a weight for that fields?

Comment: You need to ALTER TABLE to add new field called weight. This is SQL http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp